# d3 scale: How to use .copy()?

Tags: d3.js

I came across the [`log.copy()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#log_copy) in the [API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales). What is the purpose of this? Can someone show an example?

If I use a scale in one function, can I save it to a global variable by using `.copy()` and retrieve it later?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose is, as the name suggests, to copy a scale. You essentially get the same type of scale, domain and range twice without having to set everything twice. For example, consider the brush demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367). Instead of

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
```

the code could be

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = x.copy(),
```

which I have done [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/f35b769b0633f3d448d8). The only difference is that the code is very slightly shorter.

If you only want to retrieve a scale, there's no need to copy it. Only when you want to modify it in two different ways independently you need different scales.