# nvd3 dual X-Axis in stackedgroupedChart

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 stackedgroupchart, Now i have changed single `X-Axis` column label into multiple.
 Also i need to add secondary `X-Axis` for month names. I am using the graph in following link

http://bl.ocks.org/4629518

Now my graph is showing like, 
[image]

And i need to add months in X-Axis like this,

[image]

Now my `X-Axis` generated based on below code:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.8); 

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return dataset[d].shift; })
    .orient("bottom");
```

Please help to add secondary label for X-Axis,

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another axis with preferred scale to map

- Use [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640833/d3-scale-how-to-use-copy) function to copy the scale
- Add new domain values to the scale
- Create a new axis and add the scale
- call(axisNew) and change the transform values

  ```
  var x2 = x0.copy();
      x2.domain(["a","b","c","d"]);

  var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x2)
      .tickSize(0)
      .orient("bottom");

  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+10) + ")")
     .call(xAxis1);
  ```

Comment: It Works fine. With same example data how can i convert into below format `<nvd3 options='options' data='data' api="api" config="{refreshDataOnly: true, deepWatchData: true}"></nvd3>` . I am using same as [http://bl.ocks.org/gencay/4629518] graph

Comment: @satheesh provide jsFiddle.

Comment: I am using the same code in [https://gist.github.com/gencay/4629518#file-index-html]. I need to show this graph in custom directive.